# How ensure async request has finished before running a function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I am performing an async request to pull data from a server and then call a function after the request. My question is how do I ensure the request is complete and all data loaded before processRecords() runs?

Thanks in advance.

```
function getRecords () {
  var ids = Server.getIds();
  var allTheRecords = [];

  ids.forEach(function(recordId) {
    Server.getRecord(recordId, function (error, data) {
      if(error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        allTheRecords.push(data);
      };
    });
  });

  processRecords(allTheRecords);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the native `Promise` api to perform the async actions for you.

Using `Promise.all` you can give it an array of promises that need to be resolved before calling the `processRecords` function.

It also now more reusable as you have a `getRecord` function that you could use elsewhere in your code.

You should probably think of a way to add in the ability to get multiple records from the server if you control it though. You don't really want to fire off a bunch of network requests if you can do it in just one.

```js
// Server mock of the api you have shown
const Server = {
  getRecord(id, callback) {
    console.log('getRecord', id)
    callback(null, {id})
  },
  getIds() {
    return [1, 2, 3]
  }
}

function getRecords (ids, processRecords) {
  console.log('getRecords', ids.join())
  // mapping the array of id's will convert them to an
  // array of Promises by calling getRecord with the id
  Promise.all(ids.map(getRecord))
    // then is called once all the promises are resolved
    .then(processRecords)
    // this will be called if the reject function of any
    // promise is called
    .catch(console.error.bind(console))
}

function getRecord(recordId) {
  // this function returns a Promise that wraps your
  // server call
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Server.getRecord(recordId, function (error, data) {
      if(error) {
        reject(error)
      } else {
        resolve(data)
      }
    })
  })
}

getRecords(Server.getIds(), function(records) {
 console.log('resolved all promises')
 console.log(records)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not sure I understand or follow though :/ I am unable to access the getRecord function as it is in a server.js file, for the purpose of this exercise I am unable to access this file. I have read about promises in passing but haven't implemented anything yet.

Comment: @LukeAveil The best way to figure out what it's doing is to put in break points in devtools and step through the code as it executes. I have modified it a little with a Mock of your Server api so it works in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

How are you performing the Asynchronous request? If it's an AJAX request, the API provides for callbacks to be supplied based on the result of the call.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: The request is performed ```Server.getRecord()```. It is not an AJAX request unfortunately...this is why I am struggling with it a bit.

Comment: Where does 'Server' come from? What API are you working with.